# How can I read the input to the pgfmathsetmacro command

Tags: input, pgfmath

I want to read the number from the external file into the **\pgfmathsetmacro** command, but it does not seem to work that way

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rotateangle}{{\input{rotateanglenum.txt}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{3}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\angle}{180}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\sum}{\angle+\rotateangle}
        \draw[blue, thin] (0,0) -- (\sum:\radius);

        \draw[red, thick] (0,0) circle (\radius cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

```
\begin{filecontents}{rotateanglenum.txt}
-10
\end{filecontents}
```

The logs read
.tex:6: Missing number, treated as zero
.
 
                   \def 
l.6 ...\rotateangle}{{\input{rotateanglenum.txt}}}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up`weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

Is it possible? Why is the problem appears?

I've tried to move the command inside the tikzpicture environment, but the compilation just stucks.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage{catchfile}` for that. What precisely is the content of `rotateanglenum.txt`?

Comment: I've added a content for example

Comment: `\CatchFileDef\rotateangle{rotateanglenum.txt}{}` with `\usepackage{catchfile}`

Comment: I think you should make your comment to an answer - it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. To make it self-contained, I produce the file `rotateanglenum.txt` with `filecontents` but you do not need this if you have the file.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{rotateanglenum.txt}
10
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\CatchFileEdef{\rotateangle}{rotateanglenum.txt}{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{3}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Angle}{180}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\Sum}{\Angle+\rotateangle}% better not use \sum
        \draw[blue, thin] (0,0) -- (\Sum:\radius);

        \draw[red, thick] (0,0) circle[radius=\radius cm];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\CatchFileDef\rotateangle{rotateanglenum.txt}{}`, as [proposed by Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525826/how-can-i-read-the-input-to-the-pgfmathsetmacro-command/525828#comment1330033_525826) also works. (I see this comment just now.)